# How to start second observable *only* after first is *completely* done in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I was under impression that `Observable.[prototype.]concat` makes sure first operation is fully finished before second operation starts. But in following code:

```
Observable
    .concat(
        Observable.fromNodeCallback(rimraf)(path.resolve('./some_dir')),
        Observable.fromNodeCallback(mkdir)(path.resolve('./some_dir')),
        writeToSomeDir$
    )
```

`mkdir` attempts (and fails) to create `./some_dir` before `rimraf` is finished deleting the dir. At the end (of throwing) however, `./some_dir` ends up getting deleted.

Why is `Observable.concat` showing such behaviour? How can I make sure first Observable is fully finished before starting with second Observable without falling to sync version of rimraf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`fromNodeCallback`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromnodecallback.md) creates a function that when invoked executes the underlying function and returns the result of the invocation through an `Observable`. Essentially the `Observable` return value is replacing the node style callback you would normally have to pass as the last argument to the function. However, the function still gets invoked immediately.

If you want to delay the execution of the methods you can wrap them in `defer` to prevent their execution until the `Observables` are subscribed to.

```
var rimrafObservable = Observable.fromNodeCallback(rimraf);
var mkdirObservable = Observable.fromNodeCallback(mkdir);

Observable
    .concat(
        Observable.defer(() => rimrafObservable(path.resolve('./some_dir'))),
        Observable.defer(() => mkdirObservable(path.resolve('./some_dir'))),
        writeToSomeDir$
    );
```